# jQuery: Return to original value when click it and link is active

Tags: jquery, html, css

My jQuery function I need change link pseudo-classes after click it and it is active and subpages in menu when are opened.

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu uk-nav-offcanvas">
<li class="menu-item-has-children uk-open">
<a href="#">ITEM</a></li></ul>
```

My jquery:

```
 (function( $ ) {
        $( '.uk-nav-offcanvas .menu-item-has-children > a' ).attr( 'href', '#' );
        if($('li.menu-item-has-children').hasClass('uk-open')){
        $( '.uk-nav-offcanvas .menu-item-has-children > a' ).attr( '#', 'href' );   
            }
        })( jQuery );
```

Comment: What is `Attr`? Fix your typo

Comment: Can you post the HTML too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep the value intact as the original one, you can store the original value in a variable and you can then set it later

```
var attrValue = $( '.uk-nav-offcanvas .menu-item-has-children > a' ).attr( 'href');
$( '.uk-nav-offcanvas .menu-item-has-children > a' ).attr( 'href', '#' );

if($('li.menu-item-has-children').hasClass('uk-open')){
    $( '.uk-nav-offcanvas .menu-item-has-children > a' ).attr('href', attrValue);
```

Comment: It's sound good but attribute not return default. i update my question.

Comment: Default value means the value which was there before changing the arttribute?

Comment: exactly .attr( '#', 'href' );

Comment: My problem is canvas menu that when click link change page but not open submenu, and when return to menu submenu is open and i can click on submenu links. I need that when click one time open submenu after can choose parent or child link.

Comment: It's good there are not error but the attribute is not change after first command .attr( 'href', '#' ); is always #

Comment: I m sorry where can i display output console.log?

Comment: if i put attrValue in console of development bar chrome i return VM6769:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: attrValue is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:13

Comment: Put console.log after `var attrValue = $`

Comment: same VM7953:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: attrValue is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1

Comment: As the discussion is getting very long here, could you please close this and mark it correct as it answers the original question and post another question. Thanks.

Comment: But we need only this var attrValue = 'href';